# Reindex Product price problem

Tags: magento-1.7, price, reindex

Can you help me with next problem: when i try make reindex via SSH i get error: [image] then i try via admin panel make reindex Product price and also get error: There was a problem with reindexing process. And all, half of the products I just do not see and do not see the newly added products

I use magento 1.7.0.2, how i can solve problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the var/locks directory?

Comment: yes, sure, and cache is empty

Comment: Have you add any SQL errors prior to this?

Comment: Do you have any ext that could be causing it like the Simple Configurable Products extension ?

Comment: no, in database i only make backup and database good is restore

Comment: Have you indexed with a clean version of Magento? i.e. no modules

Comment: There is also the Database repair tool http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

Comment: Let me know if that works and we can post it as the answer!

Comment: i have in magento many modules, when module is disable - reindex not work, database repair also did not help, will try export products - fault also, how can fix?

Comment: How did you disable the modules?

Comment: via Configuration - Adavanced

Comment: This doesn't actually disable the modules, it only disables the output... the modules still run. You need to actually disable them in the XML file

Comment: not work, I decided to put everything on Magento 1.8.1 with Magento 1.7.0.2 and now no problems, thanks